# Project requires latest version of Kotlin

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, build.gradle, apk

While trying to build a flutter apk, I got the following error message:

`Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                              │ │ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#plugin-and-versions, then update │ │ /home/beingnile/Desktop/kivicare_flutter/android/build.gradle:                                      │ │ ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>`

I went ahead and checked the Kotlin version required and updated the build.gradle file at the root of my project.
I have the following code in my `build.gradle` file after updating the file:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.iqonic.kivicare"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 9
        versionName "3.5.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    googleServices { disableVersionCheck = true }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.21'

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.6.0')

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'

    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
}
```

After the update, I ran `flutter clean` and tried to build the project again but I kept on getting the same error message.
What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the kotlin version in your android root project, `projectName/android/build.gradle`, instead of `projectName/android/app/build.gradle`

Change the version at ext.kotlin_version line:

```kotlin
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10' // Change here
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```